# What is 1/3 of the width using Bootstrap system?

Tags: bootstrap-5

If I define the code bellow, can I say that it is taking up 1/3 of the width of the whole container ?

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
   ...
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Note: I did some research and taking 8 from 12 columns it should be 2/3 of the whole container

Answer (score 0):

12/3 = 4 so for a col that will take up 1/3 of the screen you need to use the
col-sm-04 class

Comment: To take up 1/3 of the width i need to use col-sm-4 and for 2/3 i need to use col-sm-8. isn't it ?